# End to End Google Vision Safe Search Test

Tags: google-cloud-vision

I am using the Google Vision API to flag adult images uploaded my application.

I would like to be able to perform an "end-to-end" test where I upload an image and test that it gets handled correctly when flagged.

Does anyone know how to do this without an actual pornographic picture? As silly as this sounds, I was thinking about drawing genitals and uploading that since Google says their API handles drawings.

Answer (score 1):

So I decided that Wikipedia was a pretty safe place to search for an image which would generate an "Adult" ranking.

Here's a few of my observations

- [David](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_(Michelangelo)) by Michelangelo produces "unlikely" adult and "highly likely" racy.
- Various other artworks follow the scheme of "unlikely" being adult.
- [Vintage Nude Woman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_shape#/media/File:Vintage_photo_nude_woman_2.jpg) produces "highly likely" as adult content.

Unfortunately, this does not entirely meet my initial requirements. It is, after all, a nude photo and NSFW. But, since it is vintage and not sexually provocative by today's standards, I think it will work. I wish Google would provide a set of test images.